# Google maps giving alternate route instead of my desired route

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am using google maps to show some locations & I want to show the route that goes along the locations which I added previously on the map. But when I hit the URL, it's giving me an alternate route. I tried including 'via' in my URL but I don't see any change, HERE IS MY URL:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=14.6258911,79.6225408&destination=14.913214,79.992935&via=vinjamur&key=MY_API_KEY

**CHECK THE IMAGE BELOW FOR MORE INFO[image]**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution & I am posting my answer. It may be helpful to someone else.

I was using `&via:vinjamur`, but actually I should use `&waypoints=via:vinjamur`

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=14.6258911,79.6225408&destination=14.913214,79.992935&waypoints=via:vinjamur
&key=MY_API_KEY
```